# Solve the PDE by method of characteristics.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How to solve the following PDE using method of characteristics? Please explain the steps in detail.

$t^{2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + x^{2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} =(t+x)u$

$u(x,1)=\frac{x^{2}}{x-1}$

Comment: What did you try? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I tried to solve $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{(t+x)u}{t^{2}}$ but could'nt find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$t^{2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + x^{2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} =(t+x)u$$
System of characteristic ODEs : $\quad\frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{du}{(t+x)u}$

First family of characteristic curves, from $\quad \frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac{dx}{x^2} \quad\to\quad \frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{x}=c_1$

Second family of characteristic curves, from $\quad \frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac{dx}{x^2}= \frac{\frac1tdt+\frac1xdx}{\frac1tt^2+\frac1xx^2} = \frac{\frac1tdt+\frac1xdx}{t+x}=\frac{du}{(t+x)u}$

$\frac1tdt+\frac1xdx=\frac{du}{u} \quad\to\quad \frac{u}{tx}=c_2$

General solution of the PDE : $\quad\frac{u}{tx}=F\left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{x}\right)$
$$u(x,t)=txF\left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$F(X)$ is any differentiable function.

Condition :

$u(x,1)=\frac{x^{2}}{x-1}=1xF\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{x}\right) \quad\to\quad F\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{x}{x-1}$

With $X=1-\frac1x \quad\to\quad x=\frac{1}{1-X}\quad\to\quad F(X)=\frac{\frac{1}{1-X}}{\frac{1}{1-X}-1}=\frac1X$

Puting $F(X)=\frac1X$ into the above general solution leads to : $u=tx\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{x}\right)}$
$$u(x,t)=\frac{t^2x^2}{x-t}$$